# Что фактически происходит с массивом после присвоения ссылки на него к другому массиву в Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Останется ли сам массив `mass_2` в памяти? И если да, то возможно ли снова вернуть над ним контроль?

```java
class TestMass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;

        int[] mass_1 = new int[10];
        int[] mass_2 = new int[10];

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mass_1[i] = i;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mass_2[i] = -i;
        }

        mass_2 = mass_1; //присвоение ссылки
    }
}
```

Comment: `Останется ли сам массив mass_2 в памяти?` - да, пока сборщик мусора не решит очистить память. Он удаляет все объекты, к которым больше не привязано ни одной ссылки (то есть в случае, представленном @Igor, массив **не** будет удалён, так как существует ссылка `mass_3`, а вашем коде массив `mass_2` будет удалён). Но когда точно вызовется сборщик мусора предугадать невозможно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] mass_3 = mass_2;
mass_2 = mass_1; //присвоение ссылки
...
// вернуть над ним контроль
mass_2 = mass_3;
```